# How can I view the NTFS system files?

Tags: windows, ntfs, mft

For example, the master file table `$Mft` is one of the [NTFS system files](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-system-files.htm).

How can I view the properties of these files (e.g. size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this from within Windows itself – the NTFS driver does not allow user-space to access the internal structures.

From Linux, **use `ntfsinfo` from *ntfsprogs*.**

(Simple `ls -l '$Mft'` will work but is unlikely to display the correct size as many of these files don't even *have* a `::$DATA` stream.)